# Javascript function will not exit on Return

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function i am trying to force to exit, based on the calling site

```
function radSsnType_OnClick(obj, ssnValue) {

    if (('<%=(MySite.IsThis).ToString().ToLower() %>') == 'true') return;


   var value = $('#<%=mdSsn.ChildControl.ClientID%>').val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");

   if (!obj.checked || value == ssnValue)
       return;


        if (value == null ||
            trim(value).length <= 0 ||
            value == '<%=SSNNone%>' ||
            value == '<%=SSNUnknown%>' ||
            confirm("Would you like to clear the SSN?")) {
            var target = $find('<%=mdSsn.ChildOtherControl.ClientID%>');
            target.loadValue(ssnValue, target._LogicFirstPos);
            return;
        }




   obj.checked = false;
```

}

The first line is absolutely true. However the return is not exiting and it then runs through the function and tries to set every instance every var, which is causing an error.  I need to force this function to exit because in this case those variables are not present. why is the return not exiting the function?

Comment: `console.log('<%=(MySite.IsThis).ToString().ToLower() %>')` will show you whats the problem there, it would be fun if you would share the output with us

Comment: Are you sure that the condition is true? Have you tried console.logging it to be sure? And you should always use brackets on your conditionals.

Comment: If it doesn't return it means the condition is `false`, not `true`.

Comment: also you dont check for being `true`you check if it is a string with the characters `"true"`

Comment: Is it possible that `MySite.IsThis` is actually not `true`? What do you see when you look at the HTML source / JS source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first line is absolutely not `'true'`

if so, the return would "exit" the function

consider that `true != 'true'`

e.g  `true == 'true'` will return `false`

so whatever language you use there

```
('<%=(MySite.IsThis).ToString().ToLower() %>') != 'true'
```

you could easily verify this by printing the value to the console like:

```
console.log('<%=(MySite.IsThis).ToString().ToLower() %>')
```

Comment: There are quotes around the inserted value, so he'd test `('true') == 'true'`, which checks out.

Comment: what if he/she expects that .ToString().ToLower() would be javascript functions that would be executed? But he/she doesnt get any errors because they are not executed ^^

Comment: I'm not positive but pretty certain the OP is using C# as server: http://ideone.com/Fcbh9j What they did actually checks out, as far as I can see.

Comment: may guess would be gsp "grails server pages"

Comment: It's `ToString()`, not `toString()`, which makes me guess asp / C#.

Comment: i´m sure you are right ;-) anyway its not the javascript´s fault as the OP assumes

Comment: I have confirmed the value is in fact 'true'.  I am also not expecting a function to execute. The code is a check to basically confirm who the client is. There is a check in the code that returns true based on the client.  Essentially, IsThis can be IsClientA, IsClientB, etc. I checked for whitespace as well by wrapping my result in dummy text and it returned 'atruea', so white space isn't an issue. Yes, the server is C#.

Comment: john Smith, while it ended up being a combination of factors, your answer came the closest to being technically correct. There is a lot of stuff going on in the background and it ended up being buried somewhere deep within a .master page. If you create an actual answer instead of a comment I can give you credit.

Comment: hmn sorry i still dont understand what the actual answer has been for you :-)

Comment: A lot of the form elements on our websites are stored as database elements because they get reused with slightly varying differences (prompts, size etc.).  One of the controls is mapped to a child control that is not being used on the client in question.  There was a mismatch in the description of the control that was causing the issue.

Comment: alright, then i think use console.log to inspect the actual output of your server is is the right answer